# What is a good Microdata method for listing a list of events?

Tags: seo, microdata

I have a list of events that change over time, so items get added while others drop off after their dates expire.  For point of reference, they are conventions.  I've never used microdata before and would like to lay out the page correctly.

Should the whole page be an `itemscope` or the individual entries?  Because if you look at this example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.domain.org/events">
```

The URL that has the events list is `events` just like that example.  If you have each entry with that URL , wouldn't that be a major mistake?  So I am assuming `itemscope` should be used for the entire page of entries?  If that's right, what tag should I use instead of `itemscope` to identify each entry in the list of events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `itemscope` creates an (= one) item.

What this item should be, depends on the vocabulary you use. Both cases are conceivable: an item could be a list of events, or it could be a specific event. If the item would be a list of events, each event (that is part of this list) would itself be another, different item.

If you want to use the schema.org vocabulary, each event would be of [type `http://schema.org/Event`](http://schema.org/Event) (resp. a more specific type).

So a webpage with information about 3 (different!) events could look like:

```
<section>
  <h1>Events</h1>

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  …
  </article>

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  …
  </article>

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  …
  </article>

</section>
```

(Depending on your actual content, a list (e.g., `ul` resp. `ol`) might be appropriate.)

schema.org doesn’t define a type for a list of events. But there is a [general list type: `http://schema.org/ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList)

> A list of items of any sort—for example, Top 10 Movies About Weathermen, or Top 100 Party Songs.

So if you think that this is appropriate for your page, it could look like:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <h1>Events</h1>

  <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  …
  </article>

  <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  …
  </article>

  <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  …
  </article>

</section>
```

Now this list (`ItemList`) has three (`itemListElement`) events (`Event`).

Comment: So assuming your second example, a list of conventions could be `itemscope`s defined as `itemlistelement`s inside an `itemscope`.  However, the article's url `itemtype`, should it have the same url as the main `itemscope` since they are listed on the same page?  My list of Conventions has 3 links associated with each `article`, they are the link to the Convention, a comments page and a list of activities.  The second 2 links are on this site while the convention list obviously isn't.

Comment: @Maelish: I’m not sure if I understand you. `itemtype` does not contain the URL of the item. It is a URL that describes the kind of item (here: it’s an Event). If you want to provide an URL of the event, you could use the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url).

Comment: I guess this part is confusing me `itemtype="http://schema.org/Event`.

Comment: It just means "this element contains markup defining an an Event". You would use further itemprop attributes, such as url or name, on elements within each event's article. You might have further itemtypes contained within as well, such as a Place, Offer or PerformingGroup, each of which have their own attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your page is structured and what the main theme of your page is.  If the entire page consists of events at one particular venue, then I would recommend using the venue as your primary itemscope itemtype then including the various event markups within it.  It would also be a good idea to create a separate page for each event so that you can include a unique URL for each event.  If you want your event rich snippets to appear in Google, that is one of their requirements when a page lists multiple events.

Comment: Some of the the Events do have Activities beneath them when you click through to the next page.  Thats a good idea!